# How to generate URL of static file (Just like ASP.NET Core UrlHelper does for action methods)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way to dynamically generate absolute or relative URL for a static file from physical path? Without any hard-coding. Similar to what [UrlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_) does for action methods.

For example, if I have a physical path:

```
C:\some\path\outside\wwwroot\file.jpg
```

How do I get this absolute path:

```
https://localhost:9000/images/file.jpg
```

Static files middleware is configured as follows:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\some\path\outside\wwwroot"),
    RequestPath = "/images"
}
```

Comment: That path wouldn't give you that URL, the path would need to contain the `images` folder. But all you need to do is give the browser `/images/file.jpg` and it will work the rest out for you.

Comment: @DavidG I was hoping there was something ready-made available in ASP.NET Core to do that for me. Wanted to avoid hard-coding.

Comment: Hard coding what though? You still need to pass in value to the UrlHelper method.

Answer (score 1):

I've devised a rather inelegant and convoluted solution.

First, in `Startup.Configure`, declare two static paths:

```cs
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        RequestPath = "/images",
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\some\path\outside\wwwroot"),
    });

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        RequestPath = string.Empty,  // default behavior: static files from "/" (root)
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.WebRootPath),
    });
```

Second, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, register `StaticFileOptions` for `/images` path (To be injected into controllers/views):

```cs
    services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\some\path\outside\wwwroot");
        options.RequestPath = "/images";
    });
```

Inside controller:

```cs
    // ...
    private StaticFileOptions staticFileOptions;

    public SomeController(IOptions<StaticFileOptions> fileOptions)
    {
        this.staticFileOptions = fileOptions.Value;
    }

    private string GetBaseUrl()
    {
        var request = this.Request;
        var host = request.Host.ToUriComponent();
        var pathBase = request.PathBase.ToUriComponent();

        return $"{request.Scheme}://{host}{pathBase}";
    }

    // ...

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        const string physicalFile = @"C:\some\path\outside\wwwroot\generated-file.jpg";

        // ... omitted: generate a file

        var fileUrl = this.GetBaseUrl()
                    + this.staticFileOptions.RequestPath.ToUriComponent()
                    + (new PathString("/" + Path.GetFileName(physicalFile)).ToUriComponent());

        ViewBag.GeneratedFileURL = fileUrl;

        // ... use ViewBag.GeneratedFileURL in view as needed

        return View();
    }
```

Some of this can be wrapped inside TagHelper to make it a little bit cleaner.